# gcc linker can't find static library

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

First of all, I am on windows and I am compiling an COFF file from assembly with FASM. I want to use a function from raylib called DrawCircle(). I got my static library called libraylib.a in the same folder as my .asm files

First I run: `fasm main.asm` this returns an .obj file

Next I run: `gcc main.obj -o main -l libraylib.a`

This gives me following output: `C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibraylib.a: No such file or directory`

I've also tried: `gcc main.obj -o main libraylib.a`

This gives me following output:

```
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rcore.o):rcore.c:(.text+0x1bc4f): undefined reference to `timeEndPeriod'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rcore.o):rcore.c:(.text+0x20748): undefined reference to `timeBeginPeriod'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x3186): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateRectRgn'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x31c2): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x32b1): undefined reference to `__imp_SwapBuffers'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x463f): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x4653): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceGammaRamp'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0x465c): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xa989): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xa9b8): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xa9d5): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xab42): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xab7c): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xbc02): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDIBSection'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xbc3c): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateBitmap'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xbcd4): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xbd27): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteObject'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xc941): undefined reference to `__imp_GetDeviceCaps'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xca4c): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDCW'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xca5b): undefined reference to `__imp_SetDeviceGammaRamp'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xca64): undefined reference to `__imp_DeleteDC'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xeb95): undefined reference to `__imp_ChoosePixelFormat'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xeba3): undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xee47): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xf0c0): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xf4cc): undefined reference to `__imp_DescribePixelFormat'

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: libraylib.a(rglfw.o):rglfw.c:(.text+0xf4ee): undefined reference to `__imp_SetPixelFormat'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: `libraylib.a` is the *file* name. The library name to be used with the `-l` option is `raylib`.

Comment: As for the other errors, you need to link with the Windows libraries.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude same error if I use -l raylib